# Dynamics 365 - Create Server Side Script

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I know how to Load a JScript to interact with a field or a form within "Form Properties". However, how do I load a Script or code to process server side?

Comment: Are you looking for plugin/custom workflow activity/action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Writing server side code with Microsoft Dynamics 365](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/writing-server-side-code-with-microsoft-dynamics-365/)

> We have two choices for adding server side code into the application,
>   plugins or custom workflow activities (CWA). These are developed using
>   assemblies from the 365 SDK. Almost every event – create, update,
>   assign, and many more – that occurs in 365 starts an event pipeline.
>   These events can be subscribed to by plugins or workflows. The
>   workflows can be used to execute CWAs. The plugin or CWA can then be
>   used edit or change the execution of the event, or perform an entirely
>   new action.

Comment: If James Wood is your real name you must have a awesome life.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the code, it may be possible to re-write it as a CRM **Business Rule**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/create-business-rules-recommendations-apply-logic-form

> You can create business rules and recommendations to apply form logic
>   without writing JavaScript code or creating plug-ins. Business rules
>   provide a simple interface to implement and maintain fast-changing and
>   commonly used rules. They can be applied to Main and Quick Create
>   forms, and they work in PowerApps apps, Dynamics 365 web apps,
>   Dynamics 365 for tablets, and Dynamics 365 for Outlook (online or
>   offline mode).
>
> By combining conditions and actions, you can do any of the following
>   with business rules:
>
> - Set field values
> - Clear field values
> - Set field requirement levels
> - Show or hide fields
> - Enable or disable fields
> - Validate data and show error messages
> - Create business recommendations based on business intelligence.